# socket programming-recv() function

Tags: c, sockets

i have a problem with recv() function in non-blocking socket (c language under unix)
i have set socket to be non-blocking with below code(server program):

```
int x;
x=fcntl(listen_sd,F_GETFL,0);
fcntl(listen_sd,F_SETFL,x | O_NONBLOCK);
```

when i call `recv()`, if message are available it returns the length of message,if not it blocks!!

i sued select function in my code too.

```
while(1)
       {
          /**********************************************/
          /* Receive data on this connection until the  */
          /* recv fails with EWOULDBLOCK.  If any other */
          /* failure occurs, we will close the          */
          /* connection.                                */
          /**********************************************/
          rc = recv(i, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
          if (rc < 0)
          {
         if(errno == EAGAIN||errno == EWOULDBLOCK)
         {
        printf("no message\n");
        break;
         }

                perror(" recv() failed");
                close_conn = TRUE;

          }

          /**********************************************/
          /* Check to see if the connection has been    */
          /* closed by the client                       */
          /**********************************************/
          if (rc == 0)
          {
             printf("connection closed\n");
             close_conn = TRUE;
             break;


          }

          /**********************************************/
          /* Data was recevied                          */
          /**********************************************/
          len = rc;
          printf("  %d bytes received\n", len);
        }
```

if client send a message and doesn't close connection then server in first call of recv() gets message and in second call is blocked(in other words recv() doesn't return EWOULDBLOCK error at all!!)
why?

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that you are putting the `O_NONBLOCK` call into the socket you use for `listen`. But once you have called `accept` you will get *another* socket that represents the connection. This new socket may or may not have the O_NONBLOCK inherited from the other one, depending on the platform.

Citing the `man accept` from my linux:

> On Linux, the new socket returned by `accept()` does not inherit file status flags such as `O_NONBLOCK` and `O_ASYNC` from the listening socket.  This behavior differs  from the  canonical  BSD  sockets  implementation.   Portable  programs  **should not rely** on inheritance or noninheritance of file status flags and **always explicitly set all required flags** on the socket returned from `accept()`.

Comment: thanks.so you mean i must call fcntl() for every socket returned by accept?

Comment: Yes, exactly that. Or if you are using linux, you could call the GNU specific `accept4()` function, that receives an additional parameter and does that for you.

Comment: your guess was correct.i call fcntl() for every connection and its works.thanks so much

Comment: @mojtabayazdani - If you are satisfied with the answer, please do not forget to mark it as _Accepted_!